# How to increase default favicon ico image in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, favicons

> I have upload the favicon ico image 65*65 but still showing small
>   size, could you please let me know, how to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

To override the default 16px x 16px favicon manually, add your custom favicon.ico in the /Magento_Theme/web/directory.

To add favicon icons of other sizes, take the following steps:

Add your icons in the `<your_theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/web/` directory.
In the `<your_theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` layout file specify the paths to the icons and their sizes.

For example, if you added a favicon-32x32.png icon and want it to be used as a 32px x 32px favicon, your `default_head_blocks.xml` would be like following:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Theme::favicon-32x32.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" />
    </head>
</page>
```

For your changes to be applied, clear the browser cache.

Comment: So you mean don't need to upload favicon ico in admin panel and direct favicon ico file put this path as per your above given instruction?